# Кнопка back не работает WebView

Tags: java, android

Необходимо сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки Back на телефоне приложение не закрывалось. Нашел код на форуме, вроде бы расставил все куда нужно, но программа также закрывается при нажатии кнопки Back.

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.loadUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1; Mi A1 Build/N2G47H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
        @Override
                public void onBackPressed(){
            if (webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Go Back",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Exit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
                WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                    return true;
                }
            };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        }
    }
```

Код для кнопки

```
}
        @Override
                public void onBackPressed(){
            if (webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Go Back",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Exit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
```

Если webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient); вставить до webView.loadUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"); , то приложение компилируется,но все равно вылетает при нажатии клавиши back

Comment: Реализация `WebViewClient` не нужна, если вы ничего не кастомизируете, кроме перехода по ссылкам. `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` - этого достаточно. Что с остальным кодом не понять, ибо каша какая-то: отформатируйте по-человечески. Вы хотите что бы не закрывалось вообще? А как юзер будет выходить из вашей поделки?

Comment: Нет, я хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки назад у меня приложение не закрывалось, как сейчас , а переходило на одну веб страницу назад, как в обычном браузере.

Comment: Тогда этот `onBackPressed()` - то что нужно. Остальной код должен быть внутри метода `onCreate()`, включая дефолтный `WebViewClient` как я показал и `webView.loadUrl()` должен быть последним в методе. Если вылетает с ошибкой - смотрите LogCat в студии и копируйте стек ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Если не сложно не могли бы отправить полный код в ответе на вопрос. Я вроде как все сделал, но приложение также закрывается при нажатии кнопки back. Если нужно могу отправить код.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю вам нужно подтянуть теорию по структуре класса и области видимости переменных.
Не знаю насколько в этом поможет готовый код, но разжёвывать что к чему долго и нудно.

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1; Mi A1 Build/N2G47H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Go Back",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Exit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: спасибо, не заработало, но думаю вы достаточно помогли, попытаюсь сам чуть позже доделать

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

Comment: заработало с этим кодом

Comment: Странно: `Toast` не должен мешать - но в общем-то он здесь вовсе и не обязателен, в примере его использовали просто для демонстрации срабатывания логики.